# MIDI playback from sequencer extremely distorted

Tags: sound, alsa, jack, midi

I installed following packages (on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS):

```
sudo apt-get install fluidsynth qsynth qjackctl vlc vlc-plugin-fluidsynth fluid-soundfont-gm fluid-soundfont-gs qtractor
```

When I play a midi file using `fluidsynth` or using `vlc-plugin-fluidsynth` it sounds perfectly fine ( e.g. `fluidsynth Beethoven_elise.mid` )

However, when I Open the same .mid file in Qtractor, Rosegarden, or Ardour, it sounds extremely distorted (like with echos, like it is lagging, like if the computer is extremely slow, with terrible noise, like if you play multiple mp3 over each other)

I know this may be related to somethink like this *real-time-kernel* or *real-time-priority* but I allowed ('Yes') the real time priority when installing `qjackctl`.

My settings are following:

`Qsynth`

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

`qjackctl`

[image]
[image]
[image]

I was trying to play with it but did not found anything useful.

NOTE: On different computer I installed the same software and .midi files plays without problem with Qtractor. Not sure what can be wrong on this computer? (It is newer and faster).